# Do any naked-eye stars have planets

Tags: astronomy, exoplanets

Are there any known exoplanets around naked-eye stars? I know that Fomalhaut has a planet, and Vega has a dust belt that may be a protoplanetary disk or even analogous to our Kuiper belt. What else is out there orbiting naked-eye stars?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Yes.*

I'm not going to list all the stars here but it's easy to compile such a list.

Wikipedia has a [list of exoplanetary host stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exoplanetary_host_stars). If you sort the table by ascending apparent magnitude and decide how bright "naked-eye stars" need to be, you can take as many as you like from the list by taking all the stars with smaller magnitudes. I think magnitude 6 is roughly the faintest that is visible with the naked eye but it varies with your location and conditions.

For example, the exoplanet hosts with magnitudes less than 4 are Pollux, $\alpha$ Arietis, $\gamma$ Leonis, $\gamma$ Cephei, $\iota$ Draconis, $\epsilon$ Tauri, $\epsilon$ Eridani, $\beta$ Pictoris and 7 Canis Majoris.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! The list does seem incomplete, thought as Fomalhaut is missing.

Comment: @dotancohen: Fomalhaut b has [not been confirmed](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20945-new-doubts-about-poster-child-of-exoplanets.html) with radial velocity observations.

Comment: Thanks. I did know that some doubt had been shed on the existence of the planet.